# Rails on Heroku, Unicorn and Delayed Job: PG::ConnectionBadappmodels/post.rb:93 PQconsumeInput() SSL SYSCALL error: Connection timed out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, delayed-job, unicorn

I'm running a Rails 4.1.9 (Ruby 2.2.0) on heroku with unicorn and using delayed jobs to process stuff in the background. At any given moment I've got about 8 workers running.

Occasionally I'll see the following error in my logs:

```
PG::ConnectionBad
PQconsumeInput() SSL SYSCALL error: Connection timed out
app/models/post.rb:93 build
```

These errors are always coming from some background jobs I am running.

As far as I understand it, Delayed Jobs does not actually use unicorn to run workers, it's just a single worker process per worker dyno. Yet all the issues I see around this seem to stem from unicorn.

My `unicorn.rb` file looks like:

```
worker_processes 3
timeout 30
preload_app true
listen ENV['PORT'], backlog: Integer(ENV['UNICORN_BACKLOG'] || 200)

before_fork do |server, worker|

  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
    Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end

after_fork do |server, worker|

  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to sent QUIT'
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

I googled around and came across the following links:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgres-logs-errors#pgerror-ssl-syscall-error-eof-detected
- [Heroku + Sidekiq: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UnableToSend: SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802233/heroku-sidekiq-activerecordstatementinvalid-pgunabletosend-ssl-syscall)
- [Heroku + Rails + PG: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::ConnectionBad: PQconsumeInput() SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26792943/heroku-rails-pg-activerecordstatementinvalid-pgconnectionbad-pqconsum)

The first link tells me to add My config files to unicorn, the second tells me to change my `DB_REAPING_FREQUENCY`, and the third one tells me to upgrade my DB (I have the $50 a month DB already)

Any idea about what might be going wrong here and where to start fixing it? I'm not even sure where to look.

Comment: Is it always happening on the same line of code?

Comment: @steveklein yes but it's a line of code that creates a new record in the database, and the attributes are different every time.

Comment: I'm guessing you've seen [this article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job).  Never all that reassuring when the article starts off with a warning against using the technology.  If you are processing a lot of background jobs and/or experiencing long queues, you may be better off with something like Resque, which doesn't use the actual DB to manage the queue.  Either way, good luck!

Comment: @steveklein thank you! I've used resque on a few other apps before so I was definitely already considering migrating over!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up actually just being a job that took FOREVER (like 4 minutes) to run, due to some inefficient querying on my end.

Took me a remarkably long time to figure out which jobs, for such a simple and dumb solution.

I just waited until I saw that the number of jobs wasn't decreasing, ran this code:

`dj = Delayed::Job.where('run_at is not null').sample`

then got the handler with `dj.handler` to see what the actual method that was being called was, on what object, then just ran it myself and saw that it was really slow, and fixed it.